# C# detect postback in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, postback, detect

I've created an application that grabs data from a web page and saves them to a database. This pages sends some __postbacks. After the postback the page loads some data that I need to save. I do not know how to detect this event so I've created a button which grabs the data when pressed by the user. 
How can I automate the process so that the user won't have to check for the postback himself?
That is how can I detect the postback event in my webbrowser control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webbrowser control has a DocumentCompleted event. You can use the `WebBrowser.Document` property to look for something specific in this event.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
  if (webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml.Contains("some way that I know I am ready"))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I did not realize that the DocumentCompleted event would fire but I checked it and it fired 4 times! So I guess I'll have to check for the data every time which is not very hard to implement. Do you know of another way? What about the original question - can I detect the postback event somehow?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the webbrowser control.

Comment: it fired 4 times! >> For all 4 times `WebBrowser.ReadyState` would be different and you might need to process only when the status is `WebBrowserReadyState.Complete`